# Using response from a function in one method in another method in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, scope

I have this function which returns a URL and I want to use that same URL in another method. How do I do that?

Here is the code:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let imageUrl

    try {
        if (req.body.base64URL) imageUrl = await uploader(req.body.base64URL)
        else if (req.body.url) imageUrl = req.body.url
        else {
            res.redirect('/create')
            return
        }

        res.render('create', { image: imageUrl })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, 'error')
    }
})

router.post('/details', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await creator(req.body, /* use imageUrl here */)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, 'error')
    }
})
```

As you can see, I get the value of ImageUrl in a method and I want to use the same value in another method. Please help me solve it.

Comment: You could store it in a global variable.

Comment: Good to see you again @jabaa. I thought we weren't supposed to use global variables?

Comment: I would say use a class property or a variable in the next scope outside the functions but I assume it's already the global scope.

Comment: So you suggest that I use the global scope? Wouldn't it be better if I store that value in the input filed and get it from the `req` object?

Comment: Of course, the best option is to send the value in the request, either `router.post('/details/:imageUrl', async (req, res) => {` or `req.body.imageUrl`

Comment: You create `imageUrl` whenever anyone makes a POST request to `/`. You want to read it when people make a request to `/details`. But what data are they supposed to get when the request `/details`? Should the user get the last image anybody posted to `/`? The last image the same user posted there? An older image? An image from a particular different user?

Comment: I am using the `/details` route just as a `POST` request. If someone makes a `GET` request there, I am going to redirect it to `/`. This all the hassle is to make UI better so that uploading the image and adding the details are not on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as pointed out & also my original thinking behind this, since I am sending the `imageUrl` to the client in the `/ POST` route, it is advised to send back the `imageUrl` when the client hits `/details POST` route.

The way I achieved this is, I created another `input` element with display set to `none` and then added the value of `imageUrl` in that input.

This was the easiest solution to implement without making the `imageUrl` global in the backend. Also as @EcksDy mentioned, there are other methods of implementing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 3 options:

#### Send imageUrl in `/details` request

It seems your client already has the URL, since you return it in res of `/`. It would make sense to send it once more if these routes are logically separate.

#### Cache class/object

Use the servers memory to store imageUrls. Create a singleton object to serve as a cache dictionary. You will have to add some unique id in the `/` route, return it to the client and send the same id to `/details`.
The downside is that if the server crashes/restarts, you lose the images in memory.

#### Save to database

Store the imageUrls of uploaded images in a db, and return a unique id to the client. This is similar to the caching, except persistent and requires you to add a db to the design. I'm assuming "creator" function is storing the request info in a db?

---

I'm also questioning the need for 2 routes, seems like the `/` and `/details` can be merged into one. Is there a particular reason why they are separate?

Comment: If I merge the two routes, the user has to upload and add details on the same page making it unintuitive.

Comment: I'd suggest getting a little more creative with your UI :) You can let the user pick an image and then reveal another section on the page, where he fills in the details. Submitting the form will hit the merged `/details` route where you have all the data(including the image) on the req object.